# check value inside a link javascript

Tags: javascript

this is the HTML code:

```
<a class="book" type="button" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="ajaxCall(&quot;ajax_form_status&quot;, &quot;https://myweb.com/action.php?timestamp=1111111&amp;skey=2222222&amp;process=multiconfirm&amp;what=book_app&amp;fg_id=3333333&amp;result=44444444&amp;issuer_view=myweb&quot;)">13<i>:30</i></a>
```

my question is how to check this value by Javascript and get them in new window :

```
process=multiconfirm
what=book_app
fg_id=3333333
result=44444444
issuer_view=myweb
```

Comment: I'll tell you the logic you can get the value seperated by `;`

Comment: Thanks... yes , i knew but with what command javascript must use because getelementbyid or byclass not working in this example

Comment: You don't need any of these you are making an ajax call and I see you are passing  the data on click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have prepared a sample for you.

```js
var link = "https://myweb.com/action.php?timestamp=1111111&amp;skey=2222222&amp;process=multiconfirm&amp;what=book_app&amp;fg_id=3333333&amp;result=44444444&amp;issuer_view=myweb&quot;)";
var link_string = link.substring(link.indexOf("?")+1, link.length-2);
var link_values = link_string.split(";");
console.log(link_values);
```